# MS Access-How to check equality between rows

Tags: ms-access, rows, equality

I have a column that shows days like below:

```
Weekday
10
15
18
5
.
.
```

I wanna make a new column that where if a rows is the same like the previous one then to put 1 else 0

Like this:

```
Day  IS_Valid
10
10    1
8     0
8     1
```

Comment: Does not make sense.

Comment: Seems like a task for a spreadsheet.

Comment: I did in excel. it's the easiest thing. I just have almost 300000 rows and can't create other queries fast in excel.